# Adding string before php

Tags: php

I need to add a string in front of the following php code, what Is the best method of doing this?

```
<?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U') ) . __(' ago', 'yourlanguageslug'); ?><br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php echo "Posted: ".human_time_diff( get_the_time('U') ) . __(' ago', 'yourlanguageslug'); ?><br/>`

It's not that hard. but, you should these small things.

Comment: Thanks, It's literally the second time I've done anything with php.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to translate the whole string, use `printf()`.

Also, I'd escape the translations.

```
<?php printf( 
  esc_html__( 'Posted: %1$s ago', 'text-domain' ),
  human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U' ) )
); ?>
```